# I can't access the text of a TextBox in roblox LUA

Tags: lua, roblox

Alright, So I've tried other stackoverflows, But I can't get it to work.
Heres the code

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
  local plr = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.title.Frame.plr
  print(plr.Text)
  local gp = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("GetPlr")
  gp:FireServer(plr.Text)
end);
```

the frame.Plr part is the textbox
When I do plr.Text it doesn't get the current input.
I hope yall have good anwsers
And I hope you have a good day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI elements that are placed in [StarterGui](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterGui) act as a template. They are copied into each player's PlayerGui when their Character spawns in the world.

Your issue is that a player has put text into their copy of the ui, which is located in the PlayerGui, and you are trying to pull that text out of the template in StarterGui.

So in your LocalScript, try updating the path to the text box to point at the player's PlayerGui :

```
local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local pg = PlayerService.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui
    local plr = pg.ScreenGui.title.Frame.plr
    print(plr.Text)

    local gp = ReplicatedStorage.GetPlr
    gp:FireServer(plr.Text)
end)
```